# family of sets - nested union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have this set of sets:

$ A_{n,m} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{n - 1}{n+m} \leq x < n + m  \right\} $

where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$

I need to find :

1. $\bigcup_{n} \bigcap_{m} A_{n,m} $
2. $\bigcap_{n} \bigcup_{m} A_{n,m} $

So in first one I guess it's $[0, +\inf)$

And second one is $\emptyset$

But, guys, how to prove it? Tips hints?

EDIT: My tackle on first one:

$\bigcup_{n} \bigcap_{m} A_{n,m} = [-1, \infty)$

Lets assume $A_{n} = \left\{ a_{0}, a_{1}, ... , a_{k} \ where\ a_{k} = \bigcap_{m} A_{k,m} for\ k,m \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

And I'll show that $\bigcap_{m} A_{k,m} = [k-1, k)$ :

So to prove inclusions in each direction I take $x \geq k $ and so $x \notin A_{k,m}$ for $m = x-k$ Similar other way...

So having  $\bigcap_{m} A_{k,m} = [k-1, k)$ it is clear that Union such sets is continus $[k-1, k), k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\bigcup_{n} \bigcap_{m} A_{n,m} $ = $[-1, +\inf)$

Comment: Anyway you don't want $A_{0,0}$, with that definition  ;/... so is it a special case? (is it $\emptyset$, or is it $\mathbb{R}$?) I'm asking, I don't know. It's a small point, but it matters.  $\mathbb{N}$ starts at $0$ not at $1$, so for $n = 0$, $A_{0,1} = [-1, 1)$.

Comment: Good point. I'll post my tackle on first one in ~20mins

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to decide what, if anything $A_{0,0}$ is, or whether the indexing set excludes $(0,0)$, the only $(n,m)$ for which $n+m = 0$. Let's assume that it's excluded. $\mathbb{N}$ starts at $0$ not $1$.

#### The $A_{n,m}$

For $n = 0$, $A_{0,1} = [-1, 1)$; $A_{0,2} = [-\frac 1 2, 2)$, ..., and in general 
$$A_{0,m} = \left[-\frac 1 m, m\right)
$$

For $n>0$, $A_{n,0} = [\frac {n-1} n, n)$, $A_{n,1} = [\frac {n-1} {n+1}, n+1)$, ... In general (for $m > 0$):
$$A_{n,m} = \left[\frac {n-1} {n+m}, n+m\right)$$
Each is a superset of the ones before it.

#### Union of intersection

For $n = 0$:
$$
\bigcap_m A_{0,m} = [0,1)
$$
For $n > 0$:
$$
\bigcap_m A_{n,m} = \left[\frac {n-1} {n}, n\right)
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigcup_n \bigcap_m A_{n,m} &= [-1,1) \:\cup \bigcup_{n>0}\left[\frac {n-1} n, n\right) \\
&= [-1,1) \:\cup [0,+\infty) \\
&= [-1, +\infty) \\
\end{align}
$$

#### Intersection of union

For $n = 0$:
$$
\bigcup_m A_{0,m} = [-1,+\infty)
$$
For $n = 1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigcup_m A_{1,m} &= \bigcup_m \left[0, m\right) \\
&= [0, +\infty)
\end{align}
$$

For $n > 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigcup_m A_{n,m} &= \bigcup_m \left[\frac {n-1} {n+m}, n+m\right) \\
&= (0, +\infty)
\end{align}
$$
Thus the intersection of the union is:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigcap_n \bigcup_m A_{n,m} &= [-1, +\infty) \cap [0, +\infty) \cap (0, +\infty)\\
&= (0, +\infty) \\
\end{align}
$$

#### If indexes start at 1

then the union of the intersection is $[0, +\infty)$, and intersection of the union is $(0, +\infty)$.

Comment: I think that intersection of union is an empty set. $\bigcup_m A_{0,m} = [-1,+\infty)$ and $\bigcup_m A_{1,m} = [0,+\infty)$ keep going and it shrinks. Thus intersection of every such set is an empty set.

Comment: @tomtom Let's see. We have $A_{2,m} = [\frac 1 {2+m}, 2+m)$, so union over $m$ is $[1/2, 2) \cup [1/3,3) \cup [1/4,4) \cup \dots$. Which is $(0,+\infty)$. Also, $A_{1,m} = [\frac 0 {1+m}, 1+m)$ = [0, 1+m)... so union is $[0, +\infty)$. So, I'm off by {0} :) Thanks. The intersection is not empty, but it does contain 0.

Comment: No, working out the details, you wind up intersecting (0,+\infty) with that. But $n=1$ *is* a special case -- I added to the answer.